# Unable to Access Local Snapshots when external Time Machine is disconnected

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

My local snapshots are behaving weirdly. When no Time Machine backup is connected and if I enter time machine, I get this prompt:

> Your Time Machine backup disk can’t be found.

…but when my external Time Machine is connected, I can browse through both pink and white (local) coloured snapshots.

Another observation is if I go to `/Volumes` I can see the `MobileBackups` volume. When a Finder window of `/Volumes` is open and I enter Time Machine I am able to browse local snapshots even when my external time machine drive is disconnected.

Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this on several occasions and I have done this to clear up the corruption or glitch that prevents browsing local snapshots without an actual full time machine destination mounted:

1. Connect to one of my destinations and force a good backup

   ```
   tmutil startbackup --block --rotation
   ```
2. Disable local snapshots

   ```
   sudo tmutil disablelocal
   ```
3. Enable local snapshots - being sure the cleanup is done

   ```
   sudo tmutil enablelocal
   ```

I do watch the console app (or `tail -f /var/log/system.log`) during the backup and commands above to make sure that the local filesystem gets cleaned up and give the computer several minutes between the disable and the re-enable since it does have to unmount the network filesystem, delete old copies of files and clean up things before trying again with a local snapshot.

The downside of this is you do lose any copies of files that only existed on the local snapshot intervals and didn't get saved to an actual remote location. It also doesn't really dig into why the store became corrupt so you might have the same thing happen again at a later date. I've also had good luck with reproducible time machine problems reporting it to Apple for assistance. They'll want you to run `tmdiagnose` and probably not reset things like I mentioned above if you want to get at the root cause of what really happened as opposed to getting it working again.

Comment: Thank you for clear reply. I will try it out and let you know if it helps

Comment: No luck :( still same problem

Comment: Well - you might boot to recovery mode and run disk utility to see if repairing the Macintosh HD turns up any errors...

Comment: This just started happening to me after upgrading to Mavericks -- tried this advice, no luck...

Comment: I haven't been able to test these steps on Mavericks. There is a `tmdiagnose` program that will run all sorts of diagnostics on Time Machine - perhaps if you don't mind sorting through the volumes of output, it might give a better error message?